# How to push array into highcharts rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to HighCharts, JavaScript, and rails. I have a highchart in my rails application. I need to pass array into highcharts. This my method array

```
@array = OnlineBooking.joins(:room).group("rooms.name").order('count_name asc').count('name').to_a
```

Result of array --> `[["RO-04", 1], ["RO-02", 3], ["RO-03", 4]]`

Somebody can help me?

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: how to push my data to highcharts?

Comment: Is your chart in an .erb file?